# C#: Force Checking For null With Compiler

Tags: c#

I am designing an API, and some of the methods return null when they cannot complete the requested operation, like searching for an object by name. This requires all usage of these methods to check for null results, or risk exposing a bug.

Is there anyway to have a Compile-Time error/warning if the result from a method is not checked for null? For example, if you declare a variable and then use it without assigning anything, the compiler complains. The methods return Reference Types and so Nullable would not work, although it does have the behavior I want.

Throwing an Exception would also be a good solution, but as far as I know C# does not have a way to force catching an exception like Java.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes this can be very annoying especially when your having to cast it to another type so you just about have to have a junk object variable just to determine if it's null..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a third party plugin for something like that.
[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) can warn you about referencing nulls.

Comment: By the looks of it, that would be quite useful for me. It wouldn't help anyone who uses the API, but at least when I use it Resharper would help. Thank you.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this, I should note that Resharper is not free, but does have a trial.

Comment: +1 - the Code Annotations are very helpful. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Annotated_Framework

Answer (score 7):

IMO, those methods should be throwing an exception.

A lot of this could (*in theory*) be improved in 4.0 with code-contracts, since that makes it a bit more formal when a method claims to return null (or not) and demand non-null (or not).

But no; there is no inbuilt checking for this; the compiler enforces that things are *definitely assigned*, but not **what** they are assigned to. In C# 3.0 you could perhaps do something cheeky like:

```
public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T obj) where T : class {
    if(obj == null) throw new SomeException("message");
    return obj;
}
```

Then you could use this as a fluent API:

```
SomeReturnClass myObj = foo.SomeMethod().ThrowIfNull();
```

Then `myObj` will never be null...

Comment: That would throw a Run-Time exception, and so would provide no benefit over throwing an exception from the method itself. The purpose here is to have the check be Compile-Time, as the Run-Time conditions may never be met during testing. Users, being the Shakespeare writing monkeys, will, however, find it and complain.

Comment: +1 - I agree that exceptions are the answer to this issue. And C# **does** force handling an exception - if the caller doesn't it will percolate up the call stack, and if no code handles it the runtime will terminate the application.

Comment: @TrueWill - checked exceptions can allow the **compiler** to ensure exceptions are handled. I hear some people prefer this over ensuring exceptions are handled by having the application crash first, and then fixing it later - we had that behaviour to trap null pointers in assembly language :)

Comment: @TrueWill - I meant checked exceptions, but those don't exist in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The feature you're asking for is part of [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/). This extension adds precondition, postcondition, and object invariant checking.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the other answers, this is not really possible at the moment.  Could a custom rule added to [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) provide a similar purpose?

See [Creating Custom StyleCop Rules in C#](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html) for an example.